# Killall node not killing node process

Tags: command-line, nodejs, killall

I have the following output via `ps aux | grep node`:

```
karlm    17551  1.4  0.7 1000592 93604 pts/2   Sl   09:54   0:01 node -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill src/index.js --config=c.json
```

I try to kill this with `killall node`.

It doesn't kill the process though?

Comment: try `killall -s KILL node`

Comment: try `kill -s 9 17551`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The default signal sent by `killall` is `SIGTERM`

The following command uses `SIGKILL` which sometimes is needed in order to kill a process:

```
killall -s KILL node
```

More info [killall man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/killall)

> killall sends a signal to all processes running any of the specified
> commands. If no signal name is specified, SIGTERM is sent.
>
> Options:
> -s, --signal
> Send this signal instead of SIGTERM.

Comment: Thanks, never knew that different processes have different terms.

Comment: I get an error: **node: no process found**

Comment: @IgorG. - the command in my answer should kill `node`, if `node` is not running, issuing that command might result with `node: no process found`

Comment: @Yaron However, when I use `ps` to list node processes, I still see a node process running.

Comment: @IgorG. - is `node` owned by the same user which execute the `killall` command?

Comment: @Yaron `su -` user

Comment: @IgorG. - did you try running the `killall` command with the same user which own the `node` process?

Comment: @Yaron Yes sir.  I think my node script might be spawning child process ID's.  Maybe that's what causing the issue...